# How to pair external bluetooth keyboard to ubuntu touch BQ phone

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, bq, aquaris

How do I pair external bluetooth keyboard to ubuntu touch phone (Aquaris by BQ) build r22?

[image: Ubuntu Rouch BQ bluetooth keyboard]

Behaviour:

Keyboard is recognised by bluetooth manager, but button is & stays grey unable to pair.

To pair it on other OS (Android,iOS,Windows)it always first displays a dialogue with *pairing request* such this similar **example on android**:
[image]

Such *pairing request* window never displays on Ubuntu Touch :-( Keyboard is model Flyshark by iLepo.

There is untested solutions using which involves developer mode using `apt-get` to install `bluez-compat` package https://www.wayneandlayne.com/blog/2010/06/14/bluetooth-keyboard-pairing-without-code-entry/

Update: (r24) the problem remains, dialogue asking for pin shows (picture bellow). I'm able to type the number, but not find out what the numbers are :-( 
[image: Enter PIN]

Comment: I ran in to the same issue on my Meizu MX4 Ubuntu Edition, with bluetooth keyboard SilverCrest SBT 3.0 A1. I have created a bug report on Launchpad:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1478217
and referred to this article there. Please select 'this bug affects me too' and add your info there too so this issue may get more attention

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in OTA 9. Bluetooth pairing now works perfectly as per screenshot:

[image]

Thank you Ubuntu Touch development team for their great work !