# BQ Aquarius Ubuntu phone bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, phone, bq

I have SV-05B wireless bluetooth keyboard and wanted to try and connect this to my ubuntu bq phone. When I go to the blue tooth connection the mac address of the keyboard comes up but it will not connect further. Can anyone help? I looked around on the general forums but as I cannot get to to root on the phone it pretty much stops me from doing suggestions. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try tapping the device in the Bluetooth settings and clicking Connect.

If you get a PIN prompt, there's a chance you've got the same problem as described in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625533/how-to-pair-external-bluetooth-keyboard-to-ubuntu-touch-bq-phone?rq=1).

Alternatively if it appears in your connected devices but nothing happens when you press keys, you might be having the same problem as in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652066/how-to-connect-the-logitech-k810-keyboard-to-my-ubuntu-phone).

In either of those cases, it could help to draw attention to the issue by selecting 'this bug affects me too' on [this launchpad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-bluetooth/+bug/1478217). Thanks to hugo venhorst for submitting and sharing.

(I would have preferred to use a comment but I don't have enough reputation yet. If this is a poor answer I understand if it's downvoted.)