# How to connect the Logitech K810 keyboard to my Ubuntu phone?

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, bluetooth, logitech, bq

I've got an BQ Aquaris E5 Ubuntu Edition and I'm trying to connect the Logitech K810 bluetooth keyboard to it. This is probably also relevant to the K480, K811 and other Logitech bluetooth keyboards.

It will appear in the connected devices in the bluetooth settings, but the connection lights will keep flashing. When I attempt to press keys in apps such as edit, nothing happens.

I've attempted [this](http://devasive.blogspot.no/2012/11/ubuntu-1204-persistent-bluetooth-pairing.html) method as well, but `sudo bluez-simple-agent hci0 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX` does not output anything.

In the past I've successfully used the method described in [this comment](http://blog.chschmid.com/?p=1537#comment-29828) on my PC. But I'm unable to install bluez-hcidump now because there's no installation candidate.

How can I successfully connect the K810 to my phone? Preferably without doing anything that conflicts with the OTA system?